# TEdgeBrowser not working under folder path with spaces

Tags: delphi, delphi-11-alexandria

I've been stuck with this weird `TEdgeBrowser` behavior for the past couple of days. I'd appreciate if someone could shed some light here...

I created a sample project with just the below info. It works fine and loads `index.html` into the EdgeBrowser component - all is good:

```pascal
procedure TForm2.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  EdgeBrowser1.UserDataFolder := 'C:\temp';
  EdgeBrowser1.Navigate('file:///C:\Users\jimsweb\Desktop\index.html');
end;
```

Things get interesting when I move the resulting executable to a folder such as `"New Folder"` (note that there is a space in between `"New"` and `"Folder"`). Now, run the exe from `New Folder`, and the `index.html` file won't load!!  Move the executable back to a path that doesn't have spaces in it, and again the EdgeBrowser component will behave normally and load `index.html`.

I suspect that the component cannot handle paths with spaces.

How can I prevent this behavior?

Comment: Get the 8.3 filename of said folder (f.e. `dir /x "C:\ParentOfFolder\new folde*"`) and use that in the path.

Comment: @AmigoJack  there is no space in the path i'm using to display index.html. So, where can I use this 8.3 filename?

Comment: Omg, I'm sorry you guys are not following me. Please read the issue statement again. There is no issue with url. It doesn't have spaces. I understand that i need to use %20 to deal with spaces in url. As i mentioned in my post, issue is not with url. Issue happens only when I move the final executable to a path that has spaces. Again, the url I'm trying to render doesn't have spaces.. hope it helps.

Comment: I never wrote about the URI, but instead of folders and paths. If it's `Program Files` or `Program Files (x86)` then run `dir /x C:\prog*` and see if you have to use `PROGRA~1` or `PROGRA~2` to run your EXE.

Comment: @AmigoJack  I'm not using paths to run my program anywhere. It is irrelevant. I copy my exe to a "new folder" in desktop and double click to run it. Also, index.html is hard coded in the application. Issue happens only when I copy and run the exe to a folder path that has spaces. Hope I'm clear on my statement.

Comment: It is obvious to us all that the problem is with the space in "New folder".  Very simple, have you tried renaming this folder to not have spaces ?  I am voting to close this question

Comment: @RohitGupta If you are voting to close this, I'm  afraid, you did not understand the problem i was stating.

Comment: It's a component, not a full browser.  The browser does a lot of helpful things for you that a simple component will not.  So! it doesn't handle it, handle it yourself.   The component is there to interact with a page - not to handle the code that goes before the url is dispatched.

Comment: To help you, I thought I would try it myself.  The **TEdgebrowser** requires a couple of git packages which I have no wish to install.  So I tried on the **TWebBrowser**.  It all works fine in handling the html and its anchors with spaces.  I am confident that the EdgeBrowser will do the same.

Comment: @AmigoJack who says that the filesystem has short names enabled?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Nobody, I know. Yet it's a chance to just compile a second EXE which only locates f.e. `C:\good\New Folder\browser.exe` (from the current directory) and then starts `C:\good\NewFol~1\browser.exe` instead and ends itself - as buggy as the original problem sounds this workaround could be that simple.

Comment: Thanks everyone - finally I managed to make it work using @RohitGupta suggestions - use TWebBrowser instead of TEdgeBRowser. I also chose engine as EdgeBrowser.  It appears that TEdgebrowser doesn't seem handling paths with that has correctly.

Comment: Unable to reproduce here. A test works fine: `EdgeBrowser1.Navigate('file:///O:\Temp 2\index copy.html');`

Comment: Does the new folder contain `WebView2Loader.dll` or did you forget to copy it along with the EXE?